# How can I download a pre-trained model from Tensorflow's Object Detection Model Zoo?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am attempting to train an object detection model using [Tensorflow's Object Detection API 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md) and Tensorflow 2.3.0. I have largely been using [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-object-detection-using-tensorflow-from-scratch-e61da2e10087) as a resource in preparing the data and training the model.

Most articles which use the Object Detection API download a pre-trained model from the [Tensorflow model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) prior to fine-tuning.

The Tensorflow Model Zoo is a set of links on a Github page set up by the Object Detection team. When I click one such link (using Google Chrome), a new tab opens briefly as if a download is starting, then immediately closes and a download does **not** occur. Hyperlinks to other models I have found in articles also have not worked.

To anyone who has worked with fine-tuning using the Object Detection API: What method did you use to download a pre-trained model? Did the model zoo links work? If not, what resource did you use instead?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem on my own, so if anyone else is having a similar issue: try a different browser. The model zoo downloads were not working for me in Google Chrome. However, when I tried the download on Microsoft Edge, it worked immediately and I was able to proceed.

Comment: Safari on macOS worked where Chrome did not.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Chrome, you can copy the link of the model from Readme file and then paste that into another tab. The download will start automatically.